# OpenID login on local development server for google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, openid

Are you able to use open id to log into the local development server with google app engine sdk version 1.4.1 and python 2.5?

When I execute this

```
self.redirect(users.create_login_url(continue_url, None, openid_url))
```

I get redirected to http://localhost/_ah/login rather than the openid url.
The openid url and continue url are valid.

My app.yaml looks like this

```
- url: /_ah/login_required
  script: do_openid_login.py

- url: /users/(.*)
  script: routers/user_router.py
  login: required
```

If I browse to http://localhost/users/ I am also redirected to http://localhost/_ah/login rather than http://localhost/_ah/login_required

Is there a config issue or does openid not work locally?

Comment: The simple answer is openid doesn't work locally. You could however built up a so-called staging area but there's probably no offline way of telling for example who's an administrator and who's a regular user.

Comment: Could you explain this staging area idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No - in the SDK, openid logins are treated the same way as regular logins, using the same Users mockup. It's intended purely for testing.

Comment: So in dev you ignore your custom openid login page and use _ah/login? Then in production, it will use your custom open id login page?